# Is this the correct way to map system:index to a Collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, map-function

I have the code below to map the system:index (time and date, I think?) to an image collection. The ImageCollection scenes are used to calculate LST in due course, and the system:index value appended to data at export (to CSV).

I'm not sure if this bit isn't working, or the export isn't working.

```
function CloudRemoval (image) {
    var removeCloud = image.mask(image.select('BQA').eq(2720));
    return removeCloud;
  }

function systemIndex (image) {
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:index'));
    return date;
    }

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                    .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-09-30')
                    .map(CloudRemoval)
                    .map(systemIndex)
                    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[-115.50406614745035, 35.63322800145796],
            [-115.50406614745035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.63322800145796]]], null, false));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code is written, it produces following error for printing collection due **systemIndex** function must return a feature or image.

```
ImageCollection (Error)
Collection.map: A mapped algorithm must return a Feature or Image.
```

However, that function is not necessary for inserting 'system:index' in original collection because it never disappeared as property with previous treatment. So, for obtaining all 'system:index' values is preferable convert original collection in a list for returning a value different to an Image when collection is mapping with a function; as in following code.

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[-115.50406614745035, 35.63322800145796],
            [-115.50406614745035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.63322800145796]]], null, false);

function CloudRemoval (image) {
    var removeCloud = image.mask(image.select('BQA').eq(2720));
    return removeCloud;
  }

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                    .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-09-30')
                    .filterBounds(polygon)
                    .map(CloudRemoval);

print(collection);

var collection_list = collection.toList(collection.size());

var systemIndex = collection_list.map(function (image) {
    var index = ee.Image(image).get('system:index');
    return index;
    }

);

print("systemIndex", systemIndex);
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, it can be observed in following image (Console Tab), 'system:index' and 'system:time_start' properties in original collection and printed 'system:index' values for each image in referred collection.

[image]

Comment: Thanks xunilk.  Could I check I understand each step correctly?  The polygon and cloud removal functions are defined first.  The polygon is used to filter the area, and the cloud removal function is mapped across the image collection to filter for 'clear terrain' pixels.  Printing the collection lists 93 scenes , each having 37 properties.  The variable 'collection_list' creates a list containing the name of each image in the collection, it's bands, and it's metadata.  First question:

Comment: Why use var collection_list = collection.toList(collection.size()); *instead of* var collection_list = collection.toList();?  Why do we need to know the size of the collection (I can't see it is used anywhere else)?

Comment: The variable 'systemIndex' maps a function that extracts the value of 'system:index' from each image in 'collection_list' and returns this value.

Comment: 1) Yes, it's correct. If you want to return whatever thing different an image or feature you need a list. 2) It is mandatory for syntax in GEE API. If you don't use it, you will get an error. 3) Yes. You can also return, for instance, dates (with 'system:time_start instead').

Comment: Thanks, xunilk.  Now all I need to do is work out how to incorporate the systemIndex value into a CSV export.  :)

Comment: I completed your code for exporting systemIndex values as CSV. You can find it out in following link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/db264434f900b220ce0e8eec8b905878 I hope it helps.